# What does thunderous silence mean? Shouldn't it 'deafening silence'?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I encountered this in an article..., English is my second language so I am very curious..

Comment: These are essentially the same metaphorical oxymoron. In actuality, silence is neither thunderous nor deafening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two  words are practically synonymous.
A deafening silence is one that is all encompassing; nothing can be heard at all.
A thunderous silence is an oxymoron - it is a silence so profound it is, itself, loud.

Comment: If it hasn't already been extended, welcome to ELU Karmin. There’s a lot to learn here. You might benefit from a visit to the [HELP Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) & by taking the EL&U [TOUR](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). Your answer would benefit by the addition of supporting documentation from established authority, along with links to sources and citations - the goal being to create a stand alone answer. Examine other answers that have generated a good number of positive votes and emulate them.

Comment: You can examine the formatting techniques of any answer by opening the edit button below that answer (share edit flag), being careful to avoid making any unintentional edits, close by clicking cancel edit. It’s well worth looking around. Anyway, enjoy yourself, and we’ll see you around. Ping me @LittleEva if I can be of any help. :-)